# The LINQ expression could not be translated in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to use EF Core 3.1 to return rows that contain the specified phrase in any column. I am getting the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>   .Where(b => __stringProperties_0   .Any(y => __Functions_1   .Like(
>   _: y.GetValue(   obj: b,   index: null).ToString(),   matchExpression: __p_2)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by
>   inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
>   ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

How can I rewrite this query to avoid this exception?

```
public async Task<List<Table>>
        GetDataAsync(string query)
    {
        var stringProperties = typeof(Table).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == query.GetType());
        return await _context.Table
             .Where(x => stringProperties
                .Any(y => (EF.Functions.Like(y.GetValue(x, null).ToString(), "%" + query + "%"))))
             .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Does it work when you use `ToList()` on the `stringProperties` variable at the end so it gets evaluated before running into the entity framework LINQ?

Comment: I get the exception "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when trying to use ToList() in stringProperties.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this query should do it, I'm using EF.Property method here instead of reflection.

```
return await _context.Table
             .Where(x => stringProperties
                .Any(y => (EF.Functions.Like(EF.Property<string>(x, stringProperties), "%" + query + "%"))))
             .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var persons = _PersonRepository.TableNoTracking.Where(expression)
                .ProjectTo<PersonSmallInfoDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).AsEnumerable();
```

write **.AsEnumerable()** end of your code